# Show: $\sum_{i,j=1}^n |a_{ij}|^2=trA^*A=\sum^n_{i=1}\sigma_i^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace, matrix-analysis

I'm trying to prove the above fact for an arbitrary matrix $A$, with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, and singular values $\sigma_i$.

My approach so far: the trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues, and $A^*$ has the same eigenvalues as A. Diagonalize $A$, and I get the second half of the equality, since the diagonal entries of $A^*A$ are now the squares of the singular values. The first half eludes me, could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Write out the definition of trace and then use the definition of matrix multiplication
$$ \mathrm{tr}(A^\ast A) = \sum_{i} (A^\ast A)_{i, i} = \sum_{i} \sum_{j} A_{i, j}^{\ast} A_{j, i} = \sum_{i} \sum_j |A_{i, j}|^2 $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=(a_{ij})_{i,j}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$.

For the fist equality, just write everything out: if $(b_{ij})_{i,j}:=A^*A$, then $b_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n\overline{a_{ki}}a_{kj}$, so:
\begin{align*}
\text{tr}(A^*A)&=\sum_{i=1}^nb_{ii}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n\underbrace{\overline{a_{ki}}a_{ki}}_{|a_{ki}|^2}\\
&=\sum_{i,k}|a_{ik}|^2
\end{align*}
For the second, be careful: $A$ is not necessarily diagonalizable. However, since $A^*A$ is self-adjoint, it is diagonalizable and, furthermore, all its eigenvalues are real, namely $\sigma_1^2,...,\sigma_n^2$. In particular:
$$\text{tr}(A^*A)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma^2_i$$

Answer (score 0):

For the first half, just use the literal meaning of the trace. What are the diagonal entries of $A^*A$?